# Why does JPanel repaint automatically?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jpanel

I need to add 30 `JPanel`s to a big `JPanel` ( which has`FlowLayout` layout manager ) in runtime. I want to show added panels at the end, when all are added, so I `reValidate();`and`rePaint();` at the end but the big panel shows each added panel just at the time of adding, it seems that it is repainted automatically:

```
public class CalendarsManager implements Runnable
{

    public CalendarsManager(int mode, DecorateCalendarContainer container)
    {
        status = mode;
        containerPanel = container.getContainer();
        dayPanelsCategory = container.getDayPanels();
    }
    public void run()
    {
        for(int i=1;i<=30;i++)
        {
            containerPanel .add(dayPanelsCategory);
        }
        containerPanel.revalidate();
        containerPanel.repaint();
    }
}
```

Comment: All 30 panels will be displayed at the same time because you add the panels in a loop and all this code executes in a few milliseconds. If you want to see the panels added one at a time then you need to add animation to your code. Then in the animation you need to wait 100ms or so between the time you add each panel and to the revalidate and repaint. You can use a SwingWorker or a Swing Timer to do the animation.

Answer (score 3):

Alter your Swing components only from the EDT (Event Dispatch Thread), adding/removing components from any other thread leads to undefined behavior and potentially to very hard to trace race conditions.

You should use a call like SwingUtilities.invokeLater()/invokeAndWait() to execute the code that alters the GUI on the EDT. With regards to painting, this makes your invoked code atomic as well (the EDT paints the GUI, since while it is busy excuting your altering code, it can't repaint at the same time).